# Google Charts not displaying correctly

Tags: google-visualization

I am generating a URL that needs to create a PNG Graph, using Google Charts API.

I thought that I had all the parameters in the right position however the graph is not displaying correctly? It is only displaying one of the series, and even then, the series data is wrong.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
cht=lc&chs=800x350& // CHART SIZE
chco=6a6572,6a6572,6a6572,6a6572&  // SERIES COLOURS
chxr=1,-11519.670000,19297.010000&  // Y AXIS RANGE
chxt=x,y&                           //  X & Y AXIS
chxl=0:|January%2017|February%2017|March%2017|April%2017|May%2017&  // X AXIS VALUES
chdl=A|B|C|D&   //   SERIES NAMES
chtt=Sales+Year+To+DateYYYY&                         //   CHART TITLE
chts=000000,24&                                      //   CHART COLOR AND FONT SIZE
chd=t:6032,13921,0,1263,19297|-1330,-11520,-4410,490,-361|298,798,285,228,108|884,1651,1161,1473,961
// SERIES VALUES
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. For some reason the series values parameters were taking a percentage value?  So once I converted the values to a percentage of the total, it displayed fine.